# Instantiating Spring beans on demand and not at startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

Spring Boot 2.x here. I currently have a bunch of beans defined inside a `@Configuration` class like so:

```java
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {

    @Bean
    public Fizz fizz() { ... }

    @Bean
    public Buzz buzz() { ... }

}
```

Normally, Spring will fire up this class and instantiate those beans at *startup*. However, in my case, I want Spring to *skip* loading this class (and instantiating it beans) at startup, and instead do it programmatically/on demand, something like so:

```java
public void processRequest(SomeRequest request) {

    Fizz fizz = SpringAdhocLoader.load(SomeConfig.class, Fizz.class);
    Buzz buzz = SpringAdhocLoader.load(SomeConfig.class, Buzz.class);

    // use these two beans in this method somehow

}
```

There is a very specific reason why I need to do this, that falls outside the scope of this question. So I would **really** appreciate an answer of either "*Yes you can do it, and here's how...*" or "*No that can't be done with Spring and here's why...*", **instead** of answers/comments asking me *why* I want to do it. Trust me, I need to!

At the end of the day, I'm looking for a way to tell Spring *not* to instantiate all the beans in my `SomeConfig` class until another part of my code specifically wants them created. Is this possible, and if so, how?

---

#### Update

What if `Fizz` looks like this:

```java
@Component
public class Foobar {
    ...
}

public class Fizz {

    @Autowired
    private Foobar foobar;

    ...
}
```

Would the `@Lazy` annotation on `SomeConfig` *still* stave off on instantiating `Fizz` even though its autowired/injected with a `@Component` dependency?

Comment: `@Lazy` https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation

Comment: Awesome @AlanHay (+1) -- please see my update, if `Fizz` is `@Autowired` with a dependency that is a `@Component`, will this solution still work? Thanks again!

Comment: This should answer all your questions: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your exact requirements, there are various ways of accomplishing this:

- Use `@Lazy` if everyone should use the same object instance, destruction callbacks be invoked automatically, and the object created when the bean is first requested.
- Use a shorter-lived `@Scope` such as "session" or "request", if everyone within that scope should use the same object instance, destruction callbacks be invoked automatically, and the object be created when it is first requested.
- Use `@Scope("prototype")` if everyone should get a new object instance, and you are willing to invoke any destruction callbacks manually.

In all cases, injecting a "naked" bean will request the creation of that bean. You can avoid this by injecting a `Provider` instead:

```
class Foo {
    @Inject Bar bar;  // requests the creation of bar
}

class Foo {
    @Inject Provider<Bar> barProvider; // does not cause the creation of bar

    void something() {
        Bar bar = barProvider.get(); // requests the creation of bar 
    }
}
```